# How can I override cake FormHelper?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, formhelper

I need to change the $form->create behaviour, so I created a helper to use instead of the native formHelper:

SlugHelper:

```
App::import('Helper', 'Form');
class SlugFormHelper extends FormHelper {

    public function create() {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

In AppController:

```
public $helpers = array('SlugForm' => 'Form');
```

And in the View:

```
$form->create();
```

but it still calls the native `$form->create();`

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - but shouldn't you define helpers in the controller by doing something like this:

```
public $helpers = array('SlugForm', 'Form');
```

Rather than what you had with "SlugForm => Form". Hope that helps!

Comment: I wasn't trying to load 2 helpers, I was trying to load 'SlugForm' as 'Form'

Answer (score 0):

I've just been trying to do the same thing.  I think it's quite simple, just...

```
public $helpers = array('SlugForm');
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
public $helpers = array(
    'Form' => array('className' => 'MyForm'),
);
```